# Asp.net retrieve content from a Control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I will start by telling I'm not an ASC/C# developer, this is for a homework. (i hope somebody will understand what i want :D, because i dont know exactly the terms)

I have Friends.aspx and Friends.aspx.cs

In Friends.aspx i have something like

     `<%@ Reference Control="~/FriendBox.ascx" %>

      <div class="controlcontainer clearfix friendlist_containeritems" id="divFriends" runat="server">  </div>`

In Friends.aspx.cs i have this to populate divFriends:

```
foreach (FBUser user in list){   
      Control control = LoadControl("FriendBox.ascx");
      FriendBox myControl = (FriendBox)control;
      myControl.user = user;                
      divFriends.Controls.Add(myControl);                   
  }
```

In my page a have a form, and divFriends is inside the form. I have a button in this form. If i just press the button, my page gets submitted and i can retrieve values from selected checkboxes. (Every control contains a checkbox)

Everithing worked fine until i tried to submit the page via Ajax (JQuery).
My problem is that even the checkboxes are on page (i can se them, select them), when i do an ajax submit i cannot access values from checkboxes.
This is the code i use to retrieve values from checkboxes:

`foreach(Control ctrl in divFriends.Controls) {

      var friendBox = ctrl as FriendBox;
      //i can get here

      if (friendBox != null)
      { //i never get here - because friendBox is allways null }
 }`

How can i make the content from divFriends accesible when i submit my form with Jquery?
Thanks in advance.

Edit: here is the javascript i use

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.big').click(function () {
            //.big is my button 
            $('.big').attr('disabled', true);
```

```
        var form_form = $(document).find('form');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: form_form.attr('action'),
            data: form_form.serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {                    
                console.log('success');
            },
            complete: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
                $('.big').attr('disabled', false);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

});
The javascript is working because i can submit data, and i can receive data back (json), when i look at the data submited i dont have the checkboxes from divFriends.

Comment: Can you show the javascript that is submitting the form please?

Comment: That's a pretty complicated homework assignment. :/

Comment: Where in your code-behind is that foreach loop that adds controls? Which event, any logic around it? Also is there any particular reason you are adding controls dynamically like that rather than declaritively (spelling?) using a repeater/other databound control?

Answer (score 2):

The problem appears to be asp.net state managment issue. You are only adding FriendBox one time (I'm assuming, probably with an if not page.ispostback sort of thign), and not on each page hit.  Since FriendBox is added dynamically it's not surviving a postback and thus it does not exist when you try to read it.

You should add FriendBox each time the page loads, on Init before viewstate is loaded.  Adding the controls during on init will allow Viewstate to track the values and will probably fix the issue.